# LocalStore Filters and Groups Of Material-table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-table

New to React and [Material-Table](https://material-table.com/#/).

I have filters and grouping allowed in my material-table.

How can i save the filters and groups to the local storage and load them?

Answer (score 0):

you want first to

```
const newValues= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('your local storage))
```

then add your filter

```
newValues.filter()
```

finally

```
localStorage.setItem('your local storage',JSON.stringify(newValues))
```

Comment: Within material-table, there is an “ onGroupRemoved” but nothing for when a group is added. How do you trigger the local storage save when a group is added?